# How to use gocv normalize function

Tags: opencv, go, image-processing, computer-vision

I’m having troubles with gocv function Normalize. that in the documentation goes like that.

```
func Normalize(src Mat, dst *Mat, alpha float64, beta float64, typ NormType)
```

I’m calling this at my code and get a segmentation error in response. Can you help me fix this call?

```
package main

import (
“./imageprocessing”
“gocv.io/x/gocv”
// “fmt”

)
/** CovarFlags
// CovarScrambled indicates to scramble the results.
CovarScrambled CovarFlags = 0

// CovarNormal indicates to use normal covariation.
CovarNormal CovarFlags = 1

// CovarUseAvg indicates to use average covariation.
CovarUseAvg CovarFlags = 2

// CovarScale indicates to use scaled covariation.
CovarScale CovarFlags = 4

// CovarRows indicates to use covariation on rows.
CovarRows CovarFlags = 8

// CovarCols indicates to use covariation on columns.
CovarCols CovarFlags = 16
**/

func main() {

var size int

var normtype gocv.NormType = gocv.NormMinMax

size  = imageprocessing.FolderLength("./imageprocessing/Images/danger")

Images := make([]gocv.Mat,size)

GLCMs := make([]gocv.Mat,size)

normalizedGLCMs := make([]gocv.Mat,size)

means := make([]gocv.Mat,size)

imageprocessing.ReadFolder(Images,"./imageprocessing/Images/danger",true,false,false)

//GroupGLCM(Images []gocv.Mat, GLCMs []gocv.Mat, means []gocv.Mat, show bool)
imageprocessing.GroupGLCM(Images, GLCMs, means, false)

//func Normalize(src Mat, dst *Mat, alpha float64, beta float64, typ NormType)
//min value of dst is alpha and max value of dst is beta
for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
    gocv.Normalize(GLCMs[i], &normalizedGLCMs[i], 0.0, 255.0, normtype )
    //imageprocessing.ShowImage("normalizedGLCMs", normalizedGLCMs[i], 100)
}
```

Comment: It's hard to reproduce this without the implementation of ./imageprocessing. I could make a few guesses - the size of the arrays may not be `size` (but that would give an "out of range" error). Another option is that the `Normalize` doesn't take the `&normalizedGLCMs[i]` reference well, or that you have a single image in a bad format. I'd debug these by removing the slices and loop and trying to call `Normalize` on a single variable.

Comment: I was calling normalize with wrong parameters, the project is at a good stage right now, if you want to see it, here's the link https://github.com/ArielSixwings/GoDeep/tree/master